# ActionScript "?:" conditional operator and return in function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have function :

```
    public static function validate(value:*):Boolean 
    {
        ...
        if(field_counter < FIELD_LIMIT){
            field_counter++;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I want to make it one line, but it shown Syntax error on "return false":

```
field_counter < FIELD_LIMIT ? field_counter++ : return false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try working around this by testing something about the field_counter (not the nicest way but should work):

```
return (field_counter < FIELD_LIMIT ? (field_counter++!=null) :  false);
```

Comment: (field_counter++!=null) throws exception on "!null". 
And it returns false when counter is 0. Correct line is :

Comment: return (field_counter < FIELD_LIMIT ? ++field_counter :  false);

Comment: Just remember that if field_counter will be 0 it will also be interpreted as 'false' (because Boolean(0) = false), probably not an issue but worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 3):

If field_counter is not a negative number, you can forget that *if* and compute everything in a single instruction:

```
public static function validate(value:*):Boolean 
{
    return (field_counter < FIELD_LIMIT && ++field_counter)
}
```

The instruction ++field_counter will not be executed if field_counter is not lower than FIELD_LIMIT.

**Edit**

Here's a preview:
http://wonderfl.net/c/c7lA

Comment: Good answer, but question was about "?:" construction. And it return false when counter is 0.

Comment: Moving the ++ operator solves thas issue. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Why make it hard on yourself and any other developer when you can make it simple?

```
if(field_counter >= FIELD_LIMIT) 
    return false;
field_counter++;
return true;
```

Comment: Good idea, but I have big switch-case.
        public static function validate(value:*):Boolean {
            switch (value.constructor)
            {
                case WildDecorAdapter:
                    return (wild_counter < WILD_LIMIT ? ++wild_counter :  false);
                    break;
                default :
                    return (field_counter < FIELD_LIMIT ? ++field_counter :  false);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

Comment: you can't, but, you can edit your original post if you want :)

Comment: @SergeySenkov Use 4 spaces indent and an empty line before and after the code part to get it code-highlighted.

Comment: It`s possible to use double ` symbol : `Some Code Here`

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to stuff a return statement into a conditional. The trick is, the ?: operator returns a value, so you can do say `x= y>z ? 1 : z-y;` and `return` statement does not return a value in terms of an expression. You'd better leave the original if statement intact.